# Retrieve containments of an Ecore class

Tags: java, oop, ecore

I want to retrieve the containments of an Ecore class. So I have for example a structure like this:

```
class SuperClass{
    protected EObject superClassProperty;   
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    private EObject subClassProperty;
}
```

Now I want to get all the containments of the SubClass (subClassProperty).
I do it like this:

```
EList<EReference> _eAllContainments = eClass.getEAllContainments();
```

But if I do so I also get the inherited containments of the superclasses (superClassProperty). How can I just retrieve the ones that are contained in the given class (just subClassProperty)?

Comment: What's wrong about the question? Some feedback would be appropiate to ask it in a proper way.

Comment: I think you need more explanation the problem what you are facing. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're refering to ecore, I assume that you're using `EObject` elements.
Every `EObject` implements the `.eContents()` and the `.eAllContents()` method.

The difference between them is:

- `.eContents()` gives you a `List<EObject>` with all direct containment features (all features defined in the meta class with containment = true) of the Class it's called on.
- `eAllContents()` gives you a `TreeIterator<EObject>` with all containment features in a tree with your Class as root (basically it returns `.eContents()` on all of the direct `eContents()` wrapped into an iterator).

So if you only want the values of the directly contained features then simply use `eClass.eContents()`.

Because it is not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve with:

> `EList<EReference>` = _eAllContainments = eClass.getEAllContainments();

I will show you some ways to use emf to get your desired Objects.

Assuming you have an Implementation Object of your Meta-Class (you should know the difference between Implementation and the meta-class, the meta-Class is the `EClass` you're modeling and the Implementation is, well the Implemantion of this `EClass`, but the EClass is a complete independent Object) then you get your meta-EClass of your Object by calling `.eClass()` on it.

Every `EClass` has information about its declared `EReference` and its `EAttribute`, you get them by calling eg: `.getE[All]References()`, the `.getAll...` also returns all Elements of the defined Super Classes of your `EClass`.

So now you know how to get the meta-objects you defined, but how can you get the actual values representing them in your Implementation Object?

The answer is "reflection". EMF uses what is called reflective getter (`.eGet`) and setter (`.eSet`) , which take an `EStructuralFeature` and return the actual value for it.

Because every `EAttribute` and `EReference` is an `EStructuralFeature` you get the connection back from your `EClass` information to your Implementation.

FYI: you can also get EStructuralFeatures of your EClass by name, then you could do something like that:
Supposing your element has an Attribute which is called `name` then:

```
element.eGet(element.eClass().getEStructuralFeature("name"));
```

gives you the actual value for the attribute of your element.

Comment: This made things clearer. To get the containments I take `.getERefernces()` and then I check if `isContainment()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't instatiatet the superclass like:

```
    List<Superclass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Superclass());
```

so there is no instance of the subclass. Are you realy have used the right method with the correct number and type of parameters?

Does the subclass have a field where the elements are stored?

Comment: No there isn't an error in the code. I have a given Ecore model, in which the structure is already set.

Comment: Where do you get the eClass from. Are you shure you have an instance of the subclass?

What does the method _getEAllContainments()_ do? Is this a simple getter?

Comment: I'm using an existing Ecore model. The method is part of the EMF. Yes it is a simple getter and does what the name suggests.

Comment: have you tried to check wether your class object is realy an instance of your subclass?

Answer (score 0):

The following if statement checks if the ones are from the sub or a superclass:

```
eClass.getEAllContainments().get(i).EContainingClass.name == eClass.name
```